# Querying in SQL: one to many relationships among fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure as follows - there are two columns A and B. For one value of column A, there can be many values of column B (Corresponding to multiple rows). I want to query SQL in a manner that I get all the values of column A for which corresponding to one particular value of column A, column B does not take a particular value. eg:

```
    A                       B
    1                       1
    1                       2
    2                       1
    2                       3
    2                       4
    3                       2
    3                       4
    3                       5
```

If I don't want column B to have the value 3 for a particular value of column A, the query should return the following on above data

```
    A
    1
    3
```

I cannot figure out how to write such a query and searching manually is too time consuming. Please help me write the query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you question is not very clear. I understand that you want something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM table WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM table WHERE B = 3)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could use the results of one query in another. Thanks

Comment: @Suchit I edited my typo. But if you try your query you'll get 2 too, instead i believe that the OP does not want it.